# Why don’t sequences of real numbers with pointwise operations form a field?

Tags: abstract-algebra, nonstandard-analysis

I found this statement in a book introducing nonstandard analysis. It also says that “For example, let $E$ be the set of even natural numbers, and let $O$ be the set of odd natural numbers. The product of characteristic functions $\chi _E \cdot \chi _ O$ is identically 0, and should represent $0$. To have a field, therefore, one of the sequences $\chi _E$ or $\chi _O$ must also represent $0$.”

I haven’t learned representation theory (what I think it’s referring to) but I want to kinda understand this motivation in the book, without reading the whole chapters on representation theory (or just some basic algebra?).
So can anyone point out a theorem or something that could quickly make me get the overall idea?

Comment: This has nothing to do with representation theory.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To answer the question in your title: any sequence that contains $0$ doesn't have a multiplicative inverse.  But in a field, every element except $0$ (which in this case
would be the sequence of all $0$'s) must have a multiplicative inverse.

The "For example..." is essentially the case where the sequences are $0,1,0,1,0,\ldots$ and $1,0,1,0,\ldots$.  The pointwise product of these is
$0,0,0,0,0,\ldots$, which would be the $0$ element of the field.  But in a field,
the product of two elements can't be $0$ unless one of them is $0$, and that's not the case here.

Comment: Alright, I get it now. At this point I’m just curious about the characteristic functions. What are these functions for $E$ and $O$? What does “identically” mean in “identically zero”?

Comment: Identically zero means the function outputs $0$ for all inputs

Comment: see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indicator_function for characteristic functions

Comment: @MichaelMorrow Ok, one last thing I don’t understand. What does indicator function have to do with anything? Is it just that if we were to define a multiplication between two sequences as intersection we would have that $E \cdot O = 0$?